# How to prove this asymptotic formula?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

How to prove this asymptotic formula?

$$
\prod\limits_{p\leq x}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim \frac{6 e^C}{\pi^2}\log x
$$

Where we multiply over all primes less than or equal to x.

I have little idea on how to approach this. My first thought was to write $ \prod\limits_{p\leq x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \prod\limits_{p\leq x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \prod\limits_{p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: That's very good. You know that $$\prod_p \biggl(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\biggr) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$ You may need some estimates for the error of a finite partial product. Mertens has found an asymptotic for $$\prod_{p\leqslant x} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr).$$ Combine.

Comment: Thank you!, it was the missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution.
By Mertens we have: $\prod\limits_{p\leq x} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) \sim \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log x}$

Then combining as suggested by Daniel, we obtain:

$$
\prod\limits_{p≤x}\left(1 + \frac{1}{p} \right) = \frac{\prod\limits_{p≤x}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2} \right)}{\prod\limits_{p≤x}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)} \sim \frac{\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}}{\frac{1}{e^\gamma \log x}} =  \frac{6 e^\gamma}{\pi^2} \log x
$$

Comment: And just for fun. This gives: 
$$
\prod\limits_{p\leq x}\left( \frac{p+1}{p-1} \right) = \frac{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}\left( \frac{p+1}{p} \right)}{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}\left( \frac{p-1}{p} \right)} \sim \frac{\frac{6 e^\gamma}{\pi^2}\log x}{\frac{1}{e^\gamma \log x}}=\frac{6 e^\gamma \log ^2 x}{\pi^2} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to put things together, we know that:
$$\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\tag{1}$$
while [Mertens' third theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) gives:
$$\prod_{p\leq n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\sim\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log n}.\tag{2}$$